# Python telegram bot приветственное сообщение

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно вызвать команду /start по кнопке?
Т.е. пользователь заходит на канал, видит кнопку '/' или ('?'), жмет на нее, появляется кнопка '/start Справка',и, при нажатии на нее происходит отправка сообщения боту '/start' (/help). Подобное реализовано для бота @BreeZe.

```
import config
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def handle_start_help(message):
    start = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove('/start')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Welcome', reply_markup=start)
```

[image: Вот так]

Даже так, с кнопкой рарзобрался

```
mark = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove('/')
```

При нажатии в строке ввода появляется '/' , можно сделать здесь подсказки с доступными командами? /start, /stop ?

И еще вопрос, какое событие должно обрабатывать кнопку "Выход"?

Comment: Не понятно, что именно нужно сделать. Реализовать команды для бота в канале или что?

Comment: Как на скрине, начинаешь набирать /start, выше появляется кнопка
--/start Справка--
Я так понял это inline?

Comment: нет, это список обычных команд, которые задаются через @BotFather

Answer (score 2):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    user_markup.row('1⃣ Начать 1⃣   ')
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет', reply_markup=user_markup)
```

Answer (score 1):

Так можно регистрировать команды, отображаемые в интерфейсе Telegram:

```
async def set_commands(bot: Bot):
    commands = [
        BotCommand(command="/drinks", description="Заказать напитки"),
        BotCommand(command="/food", description="Заказать блюда"),
        BotCommand(command="/cancel", description="Отменить текущее действие")
    ]
    await bot.set_my_commands(commands)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто отправить клавиатуру с символом / в начале, при нажатии она отправится как команда. Или из примеров выше, добавить команды во встроенное меню телеграма. Но первая команда /start отправляется и так по кнопке самим телеграмом. Других путей я не находил.

```
keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
keyboard.row('/help', '/stop')      
bot.send_message(id, "", , reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).